# Batalha Naval Java

Tags: java, matriz

Bom dia pessoal, 
Estou fazendo um exercício em java sobre o jogo Batalha Naval, tenho boa parte do código mas estou travado na parte de validar a posição dos barcos. O exercício pede que sejam criados 4 bardos de tamanhos distintos (2,3,4,5) na posição vertical e horizontal(chamando o método) e que a posição seja aleatória, até ai ok. O problema é que as vezes um barco é construído dentro do outro, as vezes parece que sai do tabuleiro (mesmo sem a mensagem outofbounds). O método para validar se chama estaLivre (não consegui fazer muita coisa nele...)  Alguém pode me dar uma dica? Obrigado.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Random;

public class BatallaNaval {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
static BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

static int cont = 0;
static int miss = 50;
static int[][] field = new int[10][10];

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int acertos = 0;
    iniciarField();
    colocarBarco(2, 'H');
    colocarBarco(3, 'V');
    colocarBarco(4, 'H');
    colocarBarco(5, 'V');
    mostraTabuleiro();

    while(cont<14 || miss>0){
    if(cont==14||miss==0){break;}
    jogar();
    System.out.println();
    mostraTabuleiro();

    }

}

public static void iniciarField() {

    for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < field.length; j++) {

            field[i][j] = -1;
        }

    }
}

public static void colocarBarco(int longitud, char orientacion) {
     Random r = new Random();
int X;
int Y;
boolean livre = false;

if (orientacion == 'H') {

    do { 
        X = r.nextInt(9);
        Y = r.nextInt(9);
        livre = estaLivre(X, Y, longitud, 1); // 1 = horizontal
    } while(!livre); //podes alterar e colocar um limite mximo de iterações para precaver ciclos infinitos

    // se chegou aqui significa que encontraste uma posição para colocar o navio       
    for ( int i = Y; i <= Y + (longitud - 1); ++i) 
        field[X][i] = 2;

}

if (orientacion == 'V') {
  do { 
        X = r.nextInt(9);
        Y = r.nextInt(9);
        livre = estaLivre(X, Y, longitud, 0); 
    } while(!livre); 
  for ( int i = X; i <= X + (longitud - 1); ++i) 
        field[i][Y] = 2;
}
}

public static void mostraTabuleiro() {
    System.out.println("\t0\t1 \t2 \t3 \t4 \t5\t6\t7\t8\t9");
    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.print((i) + "");
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            if (field[i][j] == 0) {
                System.out.print("\t" + "*");
            } else if (field[i][j] == 1) {
                System.out.print("\t" + "X");
            } else if (field[i][j] == 2) {
                System.out.print("\t" + "B");
            } else {
                System.out.print("\t" + "~");
            }

        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}

public static void jogar() {
    try {
        System.out.print("Linha: ");
        String num1Str = in.readLine();
        int linha = Integer.parseInt(num1Str);
        System.out.print("Coluna: ");
        String numStr = in.readLine();
        int coluna = Integer.parseInt(numStr);

        if (field[linha][coluna] == 2) {
            System.out.print("Barco tocado!");
            field[linha][coluna] = 1;
            cont++;
        }
        if (field[linha][coluna] == -1) {
            System.out.print("Agua!");
            field[linha][coluna] = 0;
            miss--;
        }
        if (cont == 14) {

            System.out.print("Has ganado!");

        }
        if (miss==0){
            System.out.print("GAME OVER!");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}

// comprueba se o barco cabe

public static boolean estaLivre(int fila, int coluna, int tamanho, int direcao) {
   boolean eValido = true;

switch (direcao) {
    case 0: // Vertical
        if (fila + (tamanho - 1) >= 10) //valida se existe espaço suficiente na vertical para colocar o navio
            eValido = false;
        else
            for (int i = fila; i <= fila + (tamanho - 1) && eValido; i++)
                eValido  = eValido & (field[i][coluna] == -1);
        break;

    default: // Horizontal
        if (coluna - (tamanho - 1) >= 10) 
            eValido = false;
        else
            for (int i = coluna; i >= coluna - (tamanho- 1) && eValido; i++) 
                eValido = eValido & (field[fila][i] == -1);
        break;
}
return eValido;
```

}

}

Comment: Pensei que a questão estava esclarecida mas voltaste a abrir a pergunta. Surgiu nova dúvida?

Comment: Sim, foi mal pela demora, mas colocando exatamente como você postou  quase sempre sai do tabuleiro(outofbounds exception) ou continua colocando um por cima do outro, vou editar o código do meu primeiro post para você ver.

Comment: Fiz uma versão baseada na sua sugestão mas também  não tive sucesso...

Comment: No método estaLivre substitui "eValido  = eValido & (field[i][coluna] == -1);" por "eValido  = eValido && (field[i][coluna] == -1);". Dois && em vez de um.

Comment: Continua a mesma coisa, é muito estranho... Vou olhar o código todo para ter certeza que mais nada está influenciando no resultado, não importa o que seja colocado parece que não muda e olha que eu já criei várias versões desse código. Obrigado pela paciência e pela ajuda.

Comment: Acredito que no if(coluna - (tamanho - 1) >= 10) seja coluna + tamanho e no for i<= coluna + tamanho -1, não? Mesmo mudando esses sinais continua igual.

Comment: Podes ver a resposta editada. Penso estar a funcionar agora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui está um esboço do que podes fazer para validar se o navio pode ser colocado no tabuleiro.

```
private boolean estaLivre(int fila, int coluna, int tamanho, int direcao) {

    boolean eValido = true;

    switch (direcao) {
        case 0: // horizontal
            if (coluna + (tamanho - 1) >= 10) //valida se existe espaço suficiente na horizontal para colocar o navio
                eValido = false;
            else
                for (int i = coluna; i <= coluna + (tamanho - 1) && eValido; i++)
                    eValido  = eValido && (field[fila][i] == -1);
            break;

        default: // vertical
            if (linha + (tamanho - 1) >= 10) 
                eValido = false;
            else
                for (int i = linha; i <= linha+ (tamanho - 1) && eValido; i++) 
                    eValido = eValido && (field[i][coluna] == -1);
            break;
    }
    return eValido;
 }
```

Explicação do código:

- Recebe como parámetros a linha (fila) e a coluna onde desejas colocar a primeira posição do navio;
- Recebe também a direcção (Vertical/Horizontal) e o tamanho do navio;
- Caso desejes colocar na Vertical: Primeiro valida se o tabuleiro tem espaço suficiente: fila + (tamanho - 1) tem que ser menor que 10 (assume que o indice começa no 0 e tem 10 posições no total);
- Se passou o teste anterior significa que existe espaço para colocar o navio. Resta verificar se cada uma das posições seguintes está livre;

A validação para posicionar um navio na horizontal é semelhante.

Pormenor importante: **Este código não verifica se existem navios "encostados**". É apenas um ponto de partida para te ajudar a perceber a lógica da validação.

Como tinha dito a tua função colocaBarco também não está a funcionar bem:

```
public static void colocarBarco(int longitud, char orientacion) {

    Random r = new Random();
    int X;
    int Y;
    boolean livre = false;

    if (orientacion == 'H') {

        do { 
            X = r.nextInt(9);
            Y = r.nextInt(9);
            livre = estaLivre(X, Y, longitud, 0); // 0 = Horizontal            
        } while(!livre); 

        // se chegou aqui significa que encontraste uma posição para colocar o navio       
        for ( int i = Y; i <= Y + (tamanho - 1); ++i) 
            field[X][i] = 2;

    }

    if (orientacion == 'V') {
      do { 
            X = r.nextInt(9);
            Y = r.nextInt(9);
            livre = estaLivre(X, Y, longitud, 1); // 1 = Vertical            
      } while(!livre); 

      // se chegou aqui significa que encontraste uma posição para colocar o navio       
        for ( int i = X; i <= X + (tamanho - 1); ++1) 
            field[i][Y] = 2;   
    }
}
```

Testei esta implementação e parece que está tudo a funcionar correctamente.

Comment: Muito obrigado, esse código resolve a parte de sair do tabuleiro, certo? Quanto a estarem "encostados" é permitido o que não pode é ocuparem a mesma posição...

Comment: Sim, é uma das validações efectuadas: fila + (tamanho - 1) >= 10

Comment: Em teoria quando se põe eValido = eValido & (field[fila][i] == -1); (considerando que -1 é "áqua" e 2 é "barco") deveria resolver esse problema de dois barcos ocuparem a mesma posição, não? Estava pensando em algo assim tb mas ainda não resolve. Vou quebra a cabeça um pouco mais, obrigado pela ajuda!!

Comment: Sim. É esse o objectivo. Porquê, não funcionou?

Comment: Veja se eu fiz bobagem:

Comment: Tens um problema na função colocaBarco: Não estás a marcar correctamente as posições ocupadas pelos navios. Estás sempre a marcar a mesma: field[X][Y] = 2;

Comment: Pensava que ao colocar while(!livre) (enquanto não encontra-se uma posição correta ) e usar o random novamente, resolve-se esse problema...

Comment: Actualizei a minha resposta com ideias para alterares a tua função colocaBarco. Por favor, tenta apagar a tua resposta.

Comment: Removi, obrigado por tudo!!

Comment: Esse ++1 no for seria ++i, não?

Comment: Coloquei com ++i, que parece o correto e nada diferente, vou perguntar para o povo da minha sala se alguém conseguiu fazer e posto aqui o resultado. Obrigado

Comment: Fiz apenas uma pequena alteração no método colocaBarco. Testei a implementação e está a funcionar.

Comment: Maravilha, vou testar e olhar melhor. Obrigado.

Comment: Sim, tudo certo!!!! Muito obrigado!!